# Excel - Return value based on list of keywords that match substring

Tags: excel

Current Setup: I have two excel sheets - one with product information and one with a list of subcategories (each column of the subcategory list has a keyword that is associated with that subcategory).

Desired Result: I would like to return a subcategory for each product based on the keywords in the subcategory sheet. I am currently trying to find a way to find a substring within the product name that contains one of the keywords in the subcategory sheet and then return the relevent subcategory name.

[Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNdyj.jpg)

Comment: `find a substring within the product name that contains one of the keywords in the subcategory` there is no "kitchen" in "thomas bread cooker". You're asking the computer to think which is, currently, impossible :/

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, the first column of the subcategory sheet contains the name of the subcategory. The subsequent columns contain keywords that match the relevant subcategory, so in the above instance, 'mixer', 'cooker', and 'pan' are in separate columns in the same row as 'kitchen'

Comment: you will need to make your second table with one word per line, so Kitchen will have three lines.  One for each Mixer, Cooker and pan.  Then you would be able to do it with and INDEX/MATCH formula.  Otherwise it will take VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comments you will need to expand the lookup array to have one line per word:

[image]

Then you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1:$G$6,A1))),),0))
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

As per the photos that just got added:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$3,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$1:$I$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1:$I$3,A1))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `sumproduct`?

Comment: Great, I think your first solution makes much more sense with keeping things organized. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @findwindow Sumproduct would not work in this instance.  We need to return a text field not a number.  It would work in place of the Aggregate() if the OP could guarantee that the criteria would not be duplicate, because then the Sumproduct would bring the sum of both rows in which the value was found.  It is safer to use the Aggregate as it will return the lowest row or first value found only.

Comment: @JDStopper if this is the correct answer then please mark it correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in cell `F1`. Formula needs to be entered by pressing ctrl+shift+enter

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(C1:E1,A1)),B1,"")
```

[image]